Nuxt 3 how to update data on Laravel backend
I have a nuxt3 app, where admins are able to do basic CRUD operations. Now creating, reading and deleting works, but updating for some reason doesn't work.
here is my Edit method in nuxt:
const handleEdit = async () => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("title", editPainting.value.title || "");
    formData.append("description", editPainting.value.description || "");

    if (editPainting.value.file_path instanceof File) {
       formData.append("file_path", editPainting.value.file_path);
    }

    try {
       const token = localStorage.getItem("accessToken");
       const response = await fetch(
            `http://myapp.com/api/paintings/${editPainting.value.id}`,
             {
               method: "PUT",
               headers: {
                  Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
               },
               body: formData,
             }
       );

       if (response.ok) {
          const data = await response.json();
          const index = paintings.value.findIndex(
              (p) => p.id === data.painting.id
          );
          paintings.value.splice(index, 1, data.painting);
          editModal.value = false;
          editPainting.value = {};
        } else {
          const errorData = await response.json();
          error.value = `Failed to update the image. ${
            errorData.message || "Please try again."
          }`;
        }
      } catch (err) {
          error.value = "An error occurred. Please try again later.";
    }
 };

and then the update method in my laravel-controller:
public function update(Request $request, $id) {

       $painting = Painting::findOrFail($id);

       $validatedData = $request->validate([
          'title' => 'nullable|string',
          'description' => 'nullable|string',
          'file_path' => 'nullable|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif|max:2048'
       ]);

       $painting->title = $validatedData['title'] ?? $painting->title;
       $painting->description = $validatedData['description'] ?? $painting->description;

       if ($request->hasFile('file_path')) {
        if ($painting->file_path) {
            Storage::disk('public')->delete($painting->file_path);
        }

        $file = $request->file('file_path');
        $filename = time() . '_' . $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $filePath = $file->storeAs('paintings', $filename, 'public');

        $painting->file_path = $filePath;
      }
      
      $painting->save();

       return response()->json([
        'message' => 'Painting updated successfully',
        'painting' => $painting
       ], 200);
}

and the api route looks like this:
Route::put('paintings/{painting}', [PaintingsController::class, 'update']);

The issue is, that the update-method does not receive any data - in faxt, the Request is empty, even though the payload, which is send from the frontend is correct. So I don't really know what is going on?
Can someone help me out?
